# If $\psi:G \to H$ is a surjective homomorphism, then $|\{g \in G: \psi(g)=h_1\}| = |\{g \in G: \psi(g)=h_2\}|, \forall h_1,h_2 \in H.$

Tags: group-theory

If $\psi:G \to H$ is a surjective homomorphism, then $|\{g \in G: \psi(g)=h_1\}| = |\{g \in G: \psi(g)=h_2\}|, \forall h_1,h_2 \in H.$

Could anyone advise on the proof? If $\psi$ is injective, then the result follows. So, what happens if $\psi$ is not injective? By 2nd isomorphism thm, $G/Ker(\psi) \cong H.$ Is this the correct start? Thank you.

Comment: this sounds very interesting, but i have no clue...

Comment: I can see this if $H$ is cyclic group.. (which may not be nontrivial and may not be helpful) Do you see that?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik no $H$ doesnt have to be cyclic.

Comment: what i said is "if" H is cyclic group....

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik got it. I missed if.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: if $\psi(g_1)=\psi(g_2)$, then $\psi(g_1g_2^{-1})=1$, so $g_1g_2^{-1}\in\ker\psi$. If $K=\ker\psi$, then $g_1K=g_2K$. What about the converse?

---

Since DonAntonio spoiled the fun, here's the complete answer.

Consider $K=\ker\psi$; then we can factor $\psi$ as $\tilde\psi\circ\pi$, where $\pi\colon G\to G/K$ is the projection and $\tilde\psi$ is injective; it's also surjective, because $\psi$ is.

Thus, for $h\in H$, $\{g\in G:\psi(g)=h\}=\pi^{-1}(\tilde\psi^{-1}(h))=\pi^{-1}(g)=gK$ where $g$ is any element such that $\psi(g)=h$. So the cardinality is just $|gK|=|K|$.

---

A less “theoretical” way to look at the business is to observe that $\psi(g_1)=\psi(g_2)$ if and only if $g_1g_2^{-1}\in K=\ker\psi$, so if and only if $g_1K=g_2K$ (this is implicit in the above computation). Thus the inverse image  of $h\in H$ is just a coset $gK$, where $\psi(g)=h$. Since all cosets have the same cardinality, the result follows.

Comment: $g_1K = g_2K \Longleftrightarrow g_1g_2^{-1} \in K$

Comment: @AlexyVincenzo Yes; then…

Comment: I am unable to follow your hint.. let @AlexyVincenzo work on that could you please elaborate a bit for me... If you think extension would spoil the excitement, I would wait for some more time..

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: I'm also trying to follow his hint.

Comment: size of image of $g_1$ is $g_1K$  @AlexyVincenzo

Comment: how would that be helpful @Surya (you might want to say size of image of $g$ is $|gK|$)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik yes you are right. I meant to say if size of kernel is $n$ then homomorphism is a $n$ to $1$ mapping to the domain. Since it is surjective domain would be all of $H$. If the function was not surjective statement would have to be modified to to say for all $h_1$ and $h_2$ in the domain.

Answer (score 0):

An idea following egreg's answer:

$$\psi(g)=h_1\in H\;\implies\;\psi(gn)=h_1\;\;\forall\,n\in N:=\ker\psi\implies \psi(gN)=h_1$$

and the other way around:

$$\psi(x)=h_1\implies \psi(g^{-1}x)=\psi(g)^{-1}\psi(x)=h_1^{-1}h_1=1\implies g^{-1}x\in N\iff xN=gN$$

and thus we see that

$$\{g\in G\;;\;\phi(g)=h_1\in H\}=|gN|=|N|$$

and we're done.

Comment: I was waiting for the OP to say something; you solved the exercise.

Comment: @egreg we need a hint-only tag.

Comment: Had you commented something below your answer addressing his question(s) I could have waited...I just didn't know whether you were still on or not.

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes, I'm on. There were comments to my answer a few minutes ago. I don't think you should get in, take another person's answer and just complete it. Then, do what you like. Saying “Hint” isn't sufficient?

Comment: After 20 minutes it seems enough time for me, in particular if the answerer doesn't address questions/doubts about his/her answer, and I shall not pursue this discussion here.